# Need UpdatePanel for control, but it is causing the popup to stay open

Tags: asp.net

I have a `ModalPopupExtender`(shown below) for a widget on my site

Recently we had to implement a drop down list (`ddlEditVmrBillingType`).  One of the purposes of this was to change a label's (`lblHeaderEditNumberOfVmrBillingUnits`) text.  In order to get the event handler (`_SelectedIndexChanged`) to fire off I had to add `AutoPostBack="True"` property to the drop down list.  Next problem I had was that the label's text was not updating.  So to fix that I enclosed the panel inside of an `UpdatePanel` :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpOutterUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
<ContentTemplate>
```

However now this is causing an issue where the `ModalPopupExtender` doesnt automatically closing when the response ends.

Why is the popup not closing any longer?  Even calling pmpEditContract.Hide() or any of the other panels, from my button's onclick doesnt make them go away.

```
<!-- begin Edit Contract Modal Popup -->
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="htcEditContract" Style="display: none" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="pmpEditContract" BehaviorID="pmpBehavEditContract" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" TargetControlID="htcEditContract" PopupControlID="pcidEditContract" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" CancelControlID="ibCloseEditContract">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pcidEditContract" Style="display: none; width: 440px;" ScrollBars="None">
        <div class="popup_Container">
            <div class="popup_Titlebar">
                <asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="ppdhEditContract" Style="cursor: move; width: 100%; height: 20px;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="cursor: move;"><%=Resources.Resource.Contract %></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; cursor: pointer; padding-right: 5px;"><asp:ImageButton ID="ibCloseEditContract" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/lib/images/icn_logout.png" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:Resource, Close %>" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_Body">
                <asp:Table ID="tableContractContents" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tbl-header-AddEvent" Wrap="false"><%=Resources.Resource.ContractName %></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="divHelpdeskBox" Width="100%"><asp:TextBox ID="txtContractName" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="15px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="trDdlEditVmrBillingType">
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tbl-header-AddEvent" Wrap="false"><%= Resources.Resource.VmrBillingType %></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tbl-header-AddEvent" Wrap="false">
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEditVmrBillingType" Width="100%"  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEditVmrBillingType_SelectedIndexChanged" /></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="trTxtNumberOfPorts">
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tbl-header-AddEvent" Wrap="false"><asp:Label ID="lblHeaderEditNumberOfVmrBillingUnits" runat="server">Number Of VMR Ports</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="divHelpdeskBox" Width="100%"><asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberOfVMRBillingUnits" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="15px" CssClass="textbox" Text="0"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
```

Comment: I have had this issue before. Try placing the Pop up above the ASP.Panel. For me it worked when I placed it all the way at the top.

Comment: I have moved the update panel all around with no success of the situation changing.  thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I hate update panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is, when closing the pop up you should call your CancelControlID. The code should be,

```
Your event method
{
      ibCloseEditContract.hide();
}
```